# if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I got this error:

> if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

the code:

```
module.exports = (client, message, Discord) => {
        
    const prefix = '!'

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd)

    if (command) command.execute(client, message, Discord)
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed `message` is a valid message object

Comment: ty but I don't know how

Comment: You could log it

Comment: what it should give me cuz I get something with 2000 letters

Comment: A message object, read the object header and it's properties. You'll know if its a message if its titled "Message" and has `.content` property

Comment: no I dont thinks it is

Comment: so how can I slove it

Comment: Try reading the answer below

Answer (score 0):

`message` is not a real `Message` object. All (non-bot) messages have the [`content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) property. You need to make sure of 2 things:

1. The message is not from a bot
2. The arguments are passed in the right order

Your arguments might look something like this:

```js
(message, client, Discord)
```

but make sure it has the correct order!

```js
(client, message, Discord)
```

Comment: It is not the first reason because `Message.content` can only be a string or `null`. Just some useful info I guess.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the correct order

Comment: The bottom one is.